# How I can check if a Window has visible scrollbars using his HWND?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, winapi

I want to check if the window of an external application has the vertical or horizontal scrollbar **visible** using  the HWND (handle) of the window, exist any WinApi function to get this information? I really try the [`GetScrollInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function but it seems that not retrieve information about the visibility of the scrollbars.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about [`GetScrollBarInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `OBJID_HSCROLL` or `OBJID_VSCROLL`

> If *idObject* is OBJID_CLIENT and the window specified by hwnd is not a system scroll bar control, the system sends the SBM_GETSCROLLBARINFO message to the window to obtain scroll bar information. This allows GetScrollBarInfo to operate on a custom control that mimics a scroll bar. If the window does not handle the SBM_GETSCROLLBARINFO message, the GetScrollBarInfo function fails.

You can test `rgstate` in the [`SCROLLBARINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, there is a `STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE` flag there.

---

Another possible way is to test `GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) and (WS_HSCROLL or WS_VSCROLL) <> 0`

Comment: looks promising, but doesn't work with the Internet Explorer windows or Explorer.exe applications (Windows 7)

Comment: I believe that `Explorer.exe` contains the controls `SysTreeView32` and `SysListView32` (both return valid `WS_HSCROLL` or `WS_VSCROLL`) with `GetWindowLong`. I use Spy++ to confirm the window styles. didn't test with `GetScrollBarInfo` though.