# How I can get information about the scrollbars of an Webbrowser control instance or the IE Webrowser?

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2

I need to get information about the scrollbars (position, size, visibility) of a [Webbrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control of an external application, I tried using the [GetScrollBarInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751740/how-i-can-check-if-a-window-has-visible-scrollbars-using-his-hwnd), but the function always return false, I checked this function with another applications and works fine , but not with the IE or the Webbrowser control. `So how I can get information about the scrollbars of an Webbrowser control instance or the IE Webbrowser?`

Comment: Which versions of IE do you want this to work for assuming that different version differ in implementation

Comment: Nice information on http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/delphi-vcl-styles-and-twebbrowser-source-code-released/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can know whether the scrollbars are visible or not. Some error checking missed for brevity.

```
LPDISPATCH      lpDispatch;
lpDispatch      = m_Browser.GetDocument();

IHTMLDocument2 *doc2 = NULL;
disp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2,(void**)&doc2);

IHTMLElement *lpBodyElement; 
IHTMLBodyElement *lpBody; 

doc2->get_body(&lpBodyElement); 
if ( lpBodyElement )
{
lpBodyElement->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLBodyElement,(void**)&lpBody); 
if ( lpBody )
{
    BSTR bstrText; 
            pBody->get_scroll(&bstrText);
    lpBody->Release(); 
}
lpBodyElement->Release(); 
}
doc2->Release();
```

Possible values for bstrText are "yes", "no", "auto" (scroll bars are shown when the page content exceeds the client area)

And here is how you can know the current scroll position:

```
IHTMLElement2 *pElement = NULL;
hr = pBody->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElement2,(void**)&pElement);
ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
ASSERT( pElement );
long scroll_pos;
pElement->get_scrollTop( &scroll_pos);
```

Comment: I'm aware of this kind of method to retrieve the information of the scrollbars, but only works when the applications owns the WebBrowser control, i'm looking for a way to determine that information from an external app.

Comment: You can get the IHTMLDocument2 from a HWND of another process using this technique outlined on MSDN - [How to get IHTMLDocument2 from a HWND](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249232)

Comment: If the page uses `<!DOCTYPE>` then `body.scrollTop` will always return 0. Also the `scroll` property/attribute no longer works since IE8 standards mode.

Answer (score 7):

You can send `WM_HTML_GETOBJECT` message to `"Internet Explorer_Server"` class window of an external application to obtain `IHtmlDocument2`, then using `IServiceProvider` you can obtain `IWebBrowser2` interface.
Here is some sample code in Delphi:

```
uses
  ActiveX, MSHTML;

type
  TObjectFromLResult = function(LRESULT: lResult; const IID: TIID;
    wParam: wParam; out pObject): HRESULT; stdcall;

function GetIEFromHWND(WHandle: HWND; var IE: IWebbrowser2): HRESULT;
var
  hInst: HWND;
  lRes: Cardinal;
  Msg: Integer;
  pDoc: IHTMLDocument2;
  ObjectFromLresult: TObjectFromLresult;
begin
  Result := S_FALSE;
  hInst := LoadLibrary('Oleacc.dll');
  @ObjectFromLresult := GetProcAddress(hInst, 'ObjectFromLresult');
  if @ObjectFromLresult <> nil then
  try
    Msg := RegisterWindowMessage('WM_HTML_GETOBJECT');
    SendMessageTimeOut(WHandle, Msg, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, lRes);
    Result := ObjectFromLresult(lRes, IHTMLDocument2, 0, pDoc);
    if Result = S_OK then
      (pDoc.parentWindow as IServiceprovider).QueryService(
        IWebbrowserApp, IWebbrowser2, IE);
  finally
    FreeLibrary(hInst);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Wnd, WndChild: HWND;
  IE: IWebBrowser2;
  Document: IHtmlDocument2;
  ScrollTop, ScrollLeft: Integer;
begin
  Wnd := FindWindow('IEFrame', nil); // top level IE
  if Wnd = 0 then Exit;
  WndChild := FindWindowEX(Wnd, 0, 'Shell DocObject View', nil);
  if WndChild = 0 then Exit;
  WndChild := FindWindowEX(WndChild, 0, 'Internet Explorer_Server', nil);
  if WndChild = 0 then Exit;

  GetIEFromHWnd(WndChild, IE);
  if IE <> nil then
  begin
    ShowMessage(IE.LocationURL);
    Document := IE.Document as IHtmlDocument2;
    ScrollTop := ((Document as IHTMLDocument3).documentElement as IHTMLElement2).scrollTop;
    ScrollLeft := ((Document as IHTMLDocument3).documentElement as IHTMLElement2).scrollLeft;
    ShowMessage(Format('%d;%d', [ScrollTop, ScrollLeft]));

    // visible|hidden|scroll|auto|no-display|no-content
    ShowMessage(OleVariant(Document).documentElement.currentStyle.overflowX);
    ShowMessage(OleVariant(Document).documentElement.currentStyle.overflowY);
  end;
end;
```

---

**Edit:** when page uses `<!DOCTYPE>` directive to switch IE6 to strict
  standard-compliant mode use `document.documentElement`. (`IHTMLDocument3`)
  in pre-standard mode, the body represents the
  scrollable region, so you can retrieve the scroll position with
  `document.body.scrollTop`. In standard mode, HTML element is scrollable,
  so you should use `document.documentElement.scrollTop`.

If `document.documentElement.clientWidth <> 0` use the `documentElement` element for properties else use the `body` element.
Useful properties related to scroll information are also `clientHeight`, `scrollWidth`, `scrollHeight`.