# Is it possible to determine if a window has a scrolling function/interaction in AutoHotKey?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

For the purpose of putting more actions on fewer buttons I was hoping to detect if a window has scrolling functions. For example when a pop-up is asking you if you want to save something or not it tends to default to No. That window does not have any functionality tied to the mouse wheel action. In that scope I was planning to have the mouse wheel up and down input up or down directions. Maybe there is a way to detect if the window has scrolling enabled? Or maybe there is another work-around such as that pop-up window having a specific windows class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `GetScrollBarInfo` function in the answer here [How I can check if a Window has visible scrollbars using his HWND?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751740/how-i-can-check-if-a-window-has-visible-scrollbars-using-his-hwnd/9751776) for some useful info, but in my view, easiest is to capture window classes and fire mouse wheels accordingly, just like the example in the help for #if except you will need a correct WinTitle (use class of pop up) instead of identifying the Taskbar, and you will send `tab` and `alt+tab` in your mousewheels instead of the volume controls:

```
#If MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd")
    WheelUp::Send {Volume_Up}
    WheelDown::Send {Volume_Down}

MouseIsOver(WinTitle) {
    MouseGetPos,,, Win
    return WinExist(WinTitle . " ahk_id " . Win)
}
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Hth,